# How to use AR to scope records that have one attribute or another

Tags: activerecord

I am tryign to find trees that are dead or are over 50 years old. Imagine the `trees` table has two attributes, `status` and `age`.

Can I write:

`Tree.where('age > ? OR status = ?', 50, 'dead')`

What if I want to find trees whose age is either 50 or 100?

`Tree.where(age: [50,100])`
Is that right? Is there an alternate way to write that? Also, why is the where clause in quotes? Is that Arel?

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
Tree.where('age > ? OR status = ?', 50, 'dead')
```

This is a correct `where` clause, and no, it's not Arel. From the document [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where), you could see `where` accepts conditions in one of several formats.

- String

  - `Client.where("orders_count = '2'")`
- Array

  - `User.where(["name = ? and email = ?", "Joe", "joe@example.com"])`
- Hash

  - `User.where({ name: "Joe", email: "joe@example.com" })`

In your case, it's an array actually, not "in quotes".

2.

> What if I want to find trees whose age is either 50 or 100?
>
> `Tree.where(age: [50,100])`

Yes, it is correct. Or you could write a more explicit query:

```
Product.where('age IN (?)', [50, 100])
```